# Beamer \only or \onslide in presence of notes pages

Tags: beamer, xetex

When I use `\only<#>` in the `\note{}` section of my beamer slides, I'm getting odd behavior where an extra slide gets generated at the end of each series of slides. For example the following document:

```latex
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames,svgnames}]{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme{spruce}
\usefonttheme{serif}

\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=right}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item<1> Foo
\item<2> Bar
\end{itemize}
\note{\only<1>{Say Foo}\only<2>{Say Bar}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This results in three frames being generated, when I expected there to be only two because I only referenced slide numbers `1` and `2` in both the itemize and the `\note{}`. What gives?

Answer (score 1):

Welp, nothing rings more true right now than asking a question being the impetus needed to think of a way to answer your own question.

I can achieve the desired effect by making multiple notes, each in their own `\only<>{}`:

```latex
  \only<1>{\note{Say Foo}}
  \only<2>{\note{Say Bar}}
```

But the question still stands, as to why an `only{}` inside a `\note{}` acts so weird.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your solution! I suspect it has to do something with the way frames are counted, and I think that the notes change it.